# How can I listen for someone's process events?

Tags: c#, c++, events, process, interaction

How can I listen for someone's process events? Is it possible? For example I need to be notified to my program when player.exe(for example) stop's playing a song. Can I handle this events from memory of process as debugger?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: С++(for all platforms)/С#(for windows platform)